# The intercept are half of the real values in logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, logistic-regression, statsmodels

For a scientific study, I need to analyze the traditional logistic regression using python and sci-kit learn. After fitting my regression model with "penalty='none'", I can get the correct coefficients but the intercept is the half of the real value. My code is mostly as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
train, test = train_test_split(df, train_size = 0.8, random_state = 42)
train = train.drop(["Unnamed: 0"], axis = 1)
test = test.drop(["Unnamed: 0"], axis = 1)
x_train = train.drop(["GRUP"], axis = 1)
x_train = sm.add_constant(x_train)
y_train = train["GRUP"]
x_test = test.drop(["GRUP"], axis = 1)
x_test = sm.add_constant(x_test)
y_test = test["GRUP"]
model = sm.Logit(y_train, x_train).fit()
model.summary()
log = LogisticRegression(penalty = "none")
log.fit(x_train, y_train)
log.intercept_
```

With statsmodels I get the intercept (constant) "28.7140" but with the sci-kit learn "14.35698738". Other coefficients are same. I verified it on SPSS and the first one is the correct value. I don't want to use statsmodels only for logistic regression. Could you please help?

PS: Without intercept model works fine.

Comment: Please add your scikit-learn and statsmodels versions. Also, have you been able to reproduce this issue on another dataset? Ideally, you should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using for example a dataset included with one of these libraries.

Comment: Sci-kit learn ver. 1.0.1 and statsmodel ver. 0.12.2. Unfortunately I reproduced this issue with other datasets. Sorry, I couldn’t manage to add a minimal reproducible dataset. But I used some samples of the Goldman dataset. https://web.utk.edu/~auerbach/GOLD.htm

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that in the code you posted you add a constant term (a column of 1's) to `x_train` with `x_train = sm.add_constant(x_train)`.  Then, you pass that same `x_train` object to sklearn's `LogisticRegression()` method where the default value of `fit_intercept=` is `True`.  So, at that stage, you end up creating another constant term, causing the discrepancy in your estimated coefficients.

So, you should either turn off `fit_intercept=` in the `sklearn` code, or leave `fit_intercept=True` but use the `x_train` array without the added constant term.